# couldn't open file "" facebook error in php?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I will keep it short and sweet...

I am trying to change the facebook page tab icon/image using php sdk but I get the following error:

```
couldn't open file ""
```

I am using the code bellow:

```
$fb->api(
      $posturl3, 'POST', array(
        'custom_image' => '@' . realpath('https://mydomain.com/fbiconapp.jpg'),
        'custom_name' => 'My App', // give it a custom name if you want too
        'access_token' => $page_access_token // access token for the page
       )
);
```

i have checked and made sure the path to the image is correct and the image exists on that path. so the issue is not there.

if i remove the

```
'custom_image' => '@' . realpath('https://mydomain.com/fbiconapp.jpg')
```

from the code above, it works fine. so i know the issue is not the access token either!

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: not sure but did you checked permission on `fbiconapp.jpg`?

Comment: Pretty sure you're not supposed to use a full URL with `realpath`...

Comment: As above, realpath expects a path, not a url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in some comment, realpath is to for Path of file on machine, not a Web URI is expected there, read documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php